# Django query for mutliple time aggregations

Tags: django

I have a table of: Location | date | value (X)

I wish to produce summaries of a value (X) for a data set by day, week, month and year, for multiple locations, using the Django ORM, with a single query. e.g:

```
Location  | Mon | ... | Fri | Week Avg. | Month Avg. | Year Avg.
Location1 | 0.5 | ... | 0.8 | 0.7       | 1.1        | 1.5
Location2 | ....
```

Currently, I have to do this by multiple queries, one over days of the week, and then one each for the aggregations over the week, month and year.

Is there a smart way to do this using a single query (without returning the year's full data from the database)?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.